# In regards to SQLite3, why should I do what PHP.net tells me to?

Tags: php, sqlite

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php implies that I should do this:

```
class DB extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('database.db');
    }
}

$db = new DB();
$db->query("CREATE TABLE derp(asdf, asdf)");
```

Over this:

```
$db = SQLite3::open('database.db');
SQLite3::query("CREATE TABLE derp(asdf, asdf)");
```

Why would the folks at PHP.net have an example of a class extending SQLite3?

Comment: where does it say *not* to do the first approach?

Comment: Do you have strict warnings enabled?

Comment: It doesn’t say that you shouldn’t do that anywhere, and the comment in the second quote says _“Simple example of extending the SQLite3 class […]”_ – so maybe you just need to find a dictionary and look up what “example” means …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, it appears that neither `SQLite3::open` nor `SQLite3::query` are static methods, so accessing them in a static manner is incorrect. Instead they are instance members and you need an instance to access them. The above, and referenced, example I would imagine is also written to illustrate how you can create a reusable database driver (e.g. the `DB` object, which extends `SQLite3`) so that you don't always have to tell it which database file to open.

However, if you didn't wish to extend the `SQLite3` class, the following appears to be just as valid, and gives you similar syntax as what your second example implies that you are looking for (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php):

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.db');
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE derp(asdf STRING)");
$db->query("SELECT asdf FROM derp");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, they do NOT say "do this, not this."

They show an example (your first block of code).   I don't see a reference to your second block of code anywhere on the page, so that means it was not provided as an example - but in no way was it suggested you shouldn't use it.